# exec inside package does not call callback function

Tags: node.js, express

If I use the following code in a different file it does not call the callback function of exec. It does work if I execute the code in the main file.

**inConsole.js**

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var log = require('../includes/log');

var errorCodes = {
        30: "inEnterprise returned an error",
        40: "Unable to connect to host",
        41: "Unable to resolve hostname",
        42: "Unable to create socket",
        43: "Invalid port number",
        44: "Connect timeout",
        45: "Error sending message",
        46: "Server response timeout",
        47: "Unspecified read error",
        49: "Undefined socket error",
        50: "Invalid login information",
        57: "Invalid API version",
        51: "Contact attempts cannot exceed 99",
        52: "Contact cycle delay cannot exceed 9999",
        53: "Text device delay too large",
        54: "Invalid notification ID",
        55: "Invalid notification title",
        56: "No device or no text specified"
}

exports.post = function(req, res) {

    if(!('notification' in req.body)) {
        res.send({status: 'error', error: "notification parameter missing"});
        return;
    }

    if(req.body.notification == '') {
        res.send({status: 'error', error: "notification parameter is empty"});
        return;
    }

    if(!('message' in req.body)) {
        res.send({status: 'error', error: "message parameter missing"});
        return;
    }

    if(req.body.message == '') {
        res.send({status: 'error', error: "notification parameter is empty"});
        return;
    }

    var cmd = '/usr/local/bin/inConsole -I -i "' + req.body.notification + '" -X "' + req.body.message + '"';

    log.write_to_log("REQUEST");
    log.write_to_log(req.body);

    console.log("command: " + cmd)

    exec(cmd, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log('exec command')
        var status = {};
        if(err) {
            if(err.code in errorCodes) {
                status = {status: 'error', errorCode: err.code, errorText: errorCodes[err.code]};
            } else {
                status = {status: 'error', errorCode: err.code, errorText: "Unknown error occured"};
            }
        } else {
            var response = stdout.replace(/^(?=\n)$|^\s*|\s*$|\n\n+/gm,"").split('\n');
            status = {status: 'successful', reportId: response[response.length - 1] };
        }

        log.write_to_log("RESPONSE");   
        log.write_to_log(status);       
        res.send(status);
    })
}
```

The first console.log works but the second inside the callback does not output.

**main.js**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var express = require('/usr/lib/node_modules/express');
var app = express();

var site = require('./routes/site');
var samba = require('./routes/samba');
var inConsole = require('./routes/inConsole');

app.configure(function() {
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(express.urlencoded());
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true}));
});

// Site Routes
app.get('/', site.index);

// Samba Routes
app.get('/samba', samba.list);
app.post('/samba', samba.post);

// inConsole Routes
app.post('/inConsole', inConsole.post);

// Start server
var server = app.listen(2000, function() {
    var host = server.address().address
    var port = server.address().port
    console.log("API Server listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
});
```

No clue why this does not work..

Comment: your code is working fine for me

Comment: it does not for me... it runs everything except the callback..

Comment: looks like the problem was with pm2. It was constantly restarting because of a new log entry...

Comment: it could possible because i have commented logs entry in my code